# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. как решить

Tags: python, aiogram

`bot.py`:

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types.message import ContentTypes

import config as cfg
from db import Database
import markups as nav

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=cfg.token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database("database.db")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            db.add_user(message.from_user.id)

        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать!\nВаш счёт: {db.user_money(message.from_user)} руб.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates = True)
```

`db.py`:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`) VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def user_money(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `money` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
            return int(result[0][0])

    def set_money(self, user_id, money):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `money` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (money, user_id,))
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=InterfaceError('Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\bot.py", line 21, in start
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать!\nВаш счёт: {db.user_money(message.from_user)} руб.")
  File "C:\Users\markp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Бот\db.py", line 19, in user_money
    result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT 'money' FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchmany(1)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Answer (score 0):

21 строка

```
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать!\nВаш счёт: {db.user_money(message.from_user.id)} руб.")
```

Comment: И что же там неправильно, в 21 строке?

Comment: Похоже, что изменения содержаться в том, что в функцию `db.user_money` надо передать `message.from_user.id` вместо `message.from_user`. Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ указание на это изменение, а также причину, почему это должно помочь автору вопроса.

Comment: @wchistow Можете ответом добавить. Если этот не отредактируется.

Comment: @PetLinux, если завтра не отредактируется - добавлю.

Answer (score 0):

У вас функция `db.user_money` принимает аргумент `user_id`:

```py
def user_money(self, user_id):
#                    ^^^^^^^
```

а вы ей передаёте `message.from_user`:

```py
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать!\nВаш счёт: {db.user_money(message.from_user)} руб.")
#                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

нужно передавать именно ID:

```py
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Добро пожаловать!\nВаш счёт: {db.user_money(message.from_user.id)} руб.")
#                                                                                           Добавьте `.id`  ^^^
```